# Find process using outbound port

Tags: linux, networking

I have a server listening on port 7060, and something else local is connecting to it. How can I find the PID of the other process?

```
$ sudo netstat -plant |grep 7060
tcp6       0   0 :::7060            :::*             LISTEN      7085/java           
tcp6       0   0 127.0.0.1:35142    127.0.0.1:7060   TIME_WAIT   -
```

What process is using port 35142? `netstat` shows no process here, and I also tried `sudo lsof -n -i TCP:35142` with no output.

Comment: Your problem is that no one is using that port anymore. The process that used it has closed it (and probably exited all together), so the kernel's network stack is tracking it until the TIME_WAIT period ends (usually 2 minutes, if I recall correctly). This is to make sure the port number does not get reused while some straggling packets from the previous connection could still come in from the network. You'll need to find a way to catch the culprit process in the act.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Spiff's comment, I threw together this program to catch the process while actively connected.

```
#!/bin/bash

port=$1

[ "$port" -gt 0 ] 2>/dev/null || { echo need port number. ; exit; }

while sleep 1
do
    netstat -plant |grep :$port|grep -iv listen |\
        while read _ _ _ remote local
        do
            rpt=$(echo $remote |cut -d':' -f2)
            echo
            date
            echo $remote $local
            [ -n "$rpt" ] && lsof -n -i TCP:$rpt
        done
done
```

After a while, the `lsof` part output the other process' PID and I tracked it down.
The process was another service, still running. This program could be augmented to parse the pid from `lsof` and run `ps u $pid` for details.